# Trying to set variable from update doesn't work

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

Could anyone point out to me what's wrong with the following code, please?
It looks like perfectly legal syntax but when I run it I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "conctest"
LINE 7:  ret_id := (update conctest set id=id+1 where name = 'Billy ...
                           ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "conctest"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 66
```

Broken code:

```
DO $$

    declare ret_id integer;

begin

    ret_id := (update conctest set id=id+1 where name = 'Billy Bob' returning id);

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTable;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable AS
        select  ret_id;

END $$;

select * from tmpTable;
```

This works:

```
DO $$

    declare ret_id integer;

begin

    update conctest set id = id + 1 where name = 'Billy Bob';
    ret_id := (select id from conctest where name = 'Billy Bob');

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpTable;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpTable AS
        select ret_id;

END $$;

select * from tmpTable;
```

By the way, I copied the update clause from the working SQL query window and manually added `" returning id"` so there are no weird characters in there.
What's wrong?

TVMIA,

Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html):

> UPDATE ... RETURNING expressions INTO [STRICT] target;

try using `into` instead:

```
t=# create table s111(i int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 37.521 ms
t=# insert into s111 select 1;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 1.016 ms
t=# do
$$
declare _i int;
begin
update s111 set i =2 returning i into _i;
raise info '%',_i;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  2
DO
Time: 0.944 ms
```

Comment: Thanks, Vao - that works. I can't see this syntax on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html. I guess it's implied under "output_expression" but still a bit esoteric - if you don't know it you're up the creek.

Comment: fair point - I added link to needed documentation. assigning value to variable is plpgsql part and your link is for SQL update command